# Calling ToObject resets path of reader

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to write a converter for JSON.NET. The basic structure looks like this:

```cs
public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {

    var token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);

    Type valueType = /* Resolve the type to which the JSON value should be coerced */;

    return token.ToObject(valueType, serializer);
}
```

Calling `ToObject` and passing in the existing serializer allows me to use the same converter even when the type is nested recursively.

However, each time `ToObject` is called, the path is reset. At the breakpoint of `token.ToObject`, `reader.Path` returns the following:

```
meta.title.c
[0]
c
[0]
c
```

I would expect to see successive iterations as follows:

```
meta.title.c
meta.title.c[0]
meta.title.c[0].c
meta.title.c[0].c[0]
meta.title.c[0].c[0].c
```

How can I preserve the path between calls?

Comment: In general, you cannot.  [`JToken.Path`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L184) is computed by walking up the [`Parent`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parent.htm), getting the appropriate path component for it, then reversing and concatenating the components.  So when a `JToken` is loaded from a `JsonTextReader` there's no parent to attach to, so the containing path won't be there.  But why do you need this?  Can you share a [mcve] showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: @dbc For debugging the converter. There's an [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014826/json-net-unable-to-cast-string-to-type-with-implicit-conversion) which fails after the converter is called 5 times, and I want to see the path where it's failing. I can figure it out, but it means I have to track the path myself.